# Fixed table layout and a single row w/ pseudo element leading to shrunk table width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've a table in my project with a pseudo element to show which row is active. Having changed the table layout to fixed (which is needed), I started getting this strange layout where the active row would expand to take up the entire table, but the other rows would not:

[image: Table width issue]

I've replicated a similar problem [here](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/jOzVZpV?editors=1111) (codepen, snippet below) - it's not exactly the same (the active row doesn't extend), but I'm fairly sure any answer to this would help me fix my problem.

If you comment out the top `active::after` style you'll see the table return to its correct size.

Thanks

```js
// TABLE DATA
const headers = ['Id', 'Name', 'Age', 'Location'];

const datasetOne = [
  ['1','John Jones','27','Swindon'],
  ['2', 'Pete Best', '23', 'Glasgow'],
  ['3', 'Jules West', '22', 'Exeter'],
  ['4', 'Kate Ford', '33', 'Fife'],
];
const datasetTwo = [
  ['5','Ruth Thompson','27','Birmingham'],
  ['6', 'Dominic Lawson', '23', 'Greater London'],
  ['7', 'Really really long name', '22', 'Manchester'],
  ['8', 'Nicholas Johnson', '33', 'Liverpool'],
];


const tableWrapper = document.querySelector('.table-wrapper');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let dataset = 1;

// Listeners
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const data = formatData(datasetOne);
  tableWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', createTable(headers, data));
});
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Remove the table
  const table = document.querySelector('.table')
  table.parentElement.removeChild(table);

  // Create and insert a new table
  let data;
  if(dataset === 1) {
    data = formatData(datasetTwo);
    dataset = 2;
  }
  else if(dataset === 2) {
    data = formatData(datasetOne);
    dataset = 1;
  }
  tableWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', createTable(headers, data));
  
})

// Functions to create the table
function formatData(data) {
    const rows = data.map(row => {
        return createHTMLRow(row);
    });
    return rows;
}
function createHTMLRow([id, name, age, location]) {
    const row = [
        `<td class="td--id">${id}</td>`,
        `<td class="td--name">${name}</td>`,
        `<td class="td--age">${age}</td>`,
        `<td class="td--location">${location}</td>`
    ];
    return row;
}
function createTable (theads, rows) {
    const markup = `
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead">
                <tr>
                    ${theads.map((thead) => {
                        return `<th class="th--${thead.toLowerCase()}">${thead}</th>`;
                    }).join('')} 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody">
                ${
                    rows.map((row, index) => {
                        return `<tr class="row ${index===0? 'active':''}">${row.map(col => {
                            return `${col}`
                        }).join('')}</tr>`
                    }).join('')
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    `;
    return markup;
};
```

```css
.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: firebrick;
}


.table-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-align: start;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
.th--age, .th--id {
  width: 4rem;
}

td {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.td--name {    
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 2rem;
}



.btn {
  padding: 1rem .8rem;
  width: 7rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="btn">Change Data</div>
</div>
```

****Edit:**

@zer00ne's answer of using `min-width` did fix the row issue, but it's unfortunately caused other problems with `text-overflow:ellipsis` and column widths

If you click on the codepen, item 7 currently works and overflows as intended, and all the columns remain a fixed width, even if they aren't given a width in the css (extra space seems to be distributed evenly between them).

Adding `min-width` to the table, while fixing the row issue, unfortunately breaks this behaviour

Was hoping someone had any ideas on how I can keep the columns fixed (as the codepen currently behaves), while being able to add the pseudo element (or some way of achieving the same effect)

Thanks!

****Edit 2:**
I guess I could just manually divide up the total table width between each of the columns, but that seems a bit fragile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I believe that the pseudo-element `.active::after` may still be the culprit. It feels like a code smell, a quick google lead me to nowhere official, but from what little I found coincides with what I was saying before, It's basically an extra cell in a single row. Because it's a pseudo-element, it's not part of the DOM so if you put one in a place where other elements cannot exist (like being a child of a `<tr>`), you may get unexpected results.

So here's what I did, it looks good. Try to break it and let me know if it actually does:

I changed where `.active` is generated -- it is now assigned to the first `<td>` of the first `<tr>` within the `<tbody>`. `<td>` can hold just about anything and it looks exactly like it did as it was on the `<tr>`.

**Figure I**

```js
function formatData(data) {   // ↙️ Add the index parameter
  const rows = data.map((row, idx) => {
    return createHTMLRow(idx, row);
  });                   // ↖️ Pass it as the 1st parameter  
//...
```

**Figure II**

```js
                     // ↙️ Pass the index reference as 1st parameter
function createHTMLRow(i, [id, name, age, location]) {
  const row = [
    `<td class="td--id ${i===0? 'active':''}">${id}</td>`,
//...                     ↖️ Here's the index reference interpolated
```

---

### Original Solution

**Still good for most cases. The update is for an edge case.**

The table is at `width: 100%` which doesn't guarantee 100% with fixed tables that have undefined `<th>` widths. Change table width:

```css
table {min-width: 100%}
```

```js
// TABLE DATA
const headers = ['Id', 'Name', 'Age', 'Location'];

const datasetOne = [
  ['1', 'John Jones', '27', 'Swindon'],
  ['2', 'Pete Best', '23', 'Glasgow'],
  ['3', 'Jules West', '22', 'Exeter'],
  ['4', 'Kate Ford', '33', 'Fife'],
];
const datasetTwo = [
  ['5', 'Ruth Thompson', '27', 'Birmingham'],
  ['6', 'Dominic Lawson', '23', 'Greater London'],
  ['7', 'XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXx XXXXXX', '22', 'Manchester'],
  ['8', 'Nicholas Johnson', '33', 'Liverpool'],
];


const tableWrapper = document.querySelector('.table-wrapper');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let dataset = 1;

// Listeners
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const data = formatData(datasetOne);
  tableWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', createTable(headers, data));
});
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Remove the table
  const table = document.querySelector('.table')
  table.parentElement.removeChild(table);

  // Create and insert a new table
  let data;
  if (dataset === 1) {
    data = formatData(datasetTwo);
    dataset = 2;
  } else if (dataset === 2) {
    data = formatData(datasetOne);
    dataset = 1;
  }
  tableWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', createTable(headers, data));
});

// Functions to create the table
function formatData(data) {
  const rows = data.map((row, idx) => {
    return createHTMLRow(idx, row);
  });
  return rows;
}

function createHTMLRow(i, [id, name, age, location]) {
  const row = [
    `<td class="td--id ${i===0? 'active':''}">${id}</td>`,
    `<td class="td--name">${name}</td>`,
    `<td class="td--age">${age}</td>`,
    `<td class="td--location">${location}</td>`
  ];
  return row;
}

function createTable(theads, rows) {
  const markup = `
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead">
                <tr>
                    ${theads.map((thead) => {
                        return `<th class="th--${thead.toLowerCase()}">${thead}</th>`;
                    }).join('')} 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody">
                ${
                    rows.map((row, index) => {
                        return `<tr class="row">${row.map(col => {
                            return `${col}`
                        }).join('')}</tr>`
                    }).join('')
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    `;
  return markup;
};
```

```css
.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;  
  background-color: green;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.table-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  width: 30rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-align: start;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.th--age,
.th--id {
  width: 4rem;
}

td {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.td--name {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 2rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 1rem .8rem;
  width: 7rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-wrapper"></div>
  <div class="btn">Change Data</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had no idea that the <th>s affected the width property - always assumed it just took the width of the parent element.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually the behavior you expected is the default when the table isn't fixed, the width of `<th>` (or the first row of `<td>` if there isn't any `<th>`) is relevant when the table is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I'd just assumed it was taking the width of its parent, taking away any explicit <th> widths, and dividing the rest of the space amongst the remaining columns. I'll have to take a look at what it's really doing when I get a second! Thanks again

Comment: Also, I know it's a longshot without the code, but I don't suppose you know why the pseudo element might have had that first effect shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Yeah, the `::after` `content` occupies that space because it belongs to the `<tr>`. Even though it's 2px wide, the two `<th>` that do not have an explicit width shrinks down to the width of it's content and 1rem of padding which leaves that extra space. That `::after` `content` is like a ghost column. Although it looks valid, I've never seen `::after` applied to a `<tr>`, it seems problematic. But now you know a little more about it maybe it won't be so much a problem now.

Comment: Ah, so almost like the ghost column is sharing the extra space. Still find it a bit weird, but I'll definitely remember this now in the future, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @zer00ne - sorry to be a pain, but unfortunately the `min-width` fix has caused an issue with the table (if you compare your snippet with mine, and click 'change data' you'll see the columns expand on yours whereas the text overflows on mine - which is the effect I'm looking for). Would you mind taking another look if you get a chance? Would appreciate any insight you've got. Have updated the OP

Comment: Hey @NickW take a look at the update, let me know if it's still breaks.

Comment: Amazing, that's certainly worked on my codepen example, thanks! About to start implementing it in my project, but I think you're right about it being a pseudo-code on a <tr> issue. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "making the container conform to the table's hidden overflow" - fingers crossed that doesn't cause me problems (the container's width/alignment is set by css-grid).

Comment: What I meant by *"...making the container conform to the table's hidden overflow"*,  isn't a problem anymore since there's no more "ghost" cell, so `width: max-content` isn't needed anymore. Try setting no explicit width on `.container` first and see how that goes. I'll edit that part out, thanks.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. It's working great now, thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it